# How to redirect a domain to another using .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have recently purchased a domain name from `1&1` and I am hosting it on `000webhost`. I want to redirect the domain to another website. I tried using

```
Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas what to do?

I tried using the "redirect" button in `CPanel` but that also did not make a difference.

Comment: have you checked the error logs? hosts like 1&1 may require certain permissions on .htaccess files less you get a SoftException error preventing the .htaccess from being read. Furthermore, is there any other code in your .htaccess file? Lastly, are you sure your "A" record for your DNS correctly points to this server?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks. This was the issue, my DNS wasn't pointing to the correct servers, which made sense why the .htc access file wasn't working. Thanks a lot everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Before anything else, does your host allow the use of `.htaccess` files?  Do you have the ability tho adjust your web server config to set [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) so `.htaccess` files can be used? A sample config setting would be something like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/oldsite.com/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Use `mod_rewrite` and a `RewriteRule` like this:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note that the `^(.*)$` basically captures all traffic & parameters. Then it redirects it to `http://newsite.com/` and the `$1` then passes in the parameters to the new site. So if the old site has a URL like this:

```
  http://oldsite.com/category/item/thing
```

It will be cleanly sent to:

```
  http://newsite.com/category/item/thing
```

If you don’t want that, then just omit the `$1` like so:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

So in that second example a URL like this:

```
  http://oldsite.com/category/item/thing
```

Would just go to the root of the new site like this:

```
  http://newsite.com/
```

Also, note that the `R=301` equates to a `301 Moved Permanently`. You can change that to a `R=302` to send a `302 Moved Temporarily` if this is a temporary move.

Comment: And why would this work as opposed to a simple .htaccess redirect?

Comment: I tried this but it still does not work. When I enter my domain, it always redirects me to mydomain.com/defaultsite